# 「304 Not Modified」をハンドリングしたい

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Rails 3.2 を使っています。
ajax で get して、hoge.js.erb で処理をしています。

具体的には商品をどんどん追加していき、最後に submit で POST します。
商品を追加する部分で**稀にサーバが 304 を返す**のですが、200 でも 304 でも画面上での表示は追加された動きになります。
しかし、 POST 時に 304 が返ってきた商品は欠落(パラメータに含まれない)してしまいます。

考えられる私の案は

- 304が返ってきたらブラウザ側で描画しないで「エラー発生。もう一度追加してください」的なメッセージ出す
- ajax_fire_item アクションの時だけサーバ側で 304 を返さず、200 になるような動作にする

です。

ソースを下記に示します。

発火部分の html.erb

```
function ajax_fire_item(item_id) {
  $.get('<%= root_path -%>bills/ajax_fire_item', {pet_id: <%= @pet.id -%>, item_id: item_id});
}
```

controller

```
def ajax_fire_item
  @pet = Pet.find(params[:pet_id])
  @master_item = MasterItem.find(params[:item_id])
end
```

ajax_fire_item.js.erb

```
<% form_for([@pet, @pet.bills.build]) do |f|
  fields = f.fields_for(:bill_items, BillItem.new(master_item_id: @master_item.id, quantity: 1), :child_index => Time.now.to_i) do |builder|
    render("bill_item_fields", :f => builder)
  end
  @fields = j fields
end %>
var $item = $("<%= @fields -%>");
$item.appendTo('#item_list');

calcRow($item); // 横計
reCalc(); // 合計欄
```

試しに発火部分の html.erb を以下の様にしましたが、ログには失敗しても 111 が表示されました。

```
function ajax_fire_item(item_id) {
  $.ajax('<%= root_path -%>bills/ajax_fire_item',{
      data: {pet_id: <%= @pet.id -%>, item_id: item_id},
      type: 'GET',
      success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        // 成功処理
        console.log(111);
      },
      error: function (data, status, xhr) {
        // 失敗処理. 304error はココに来る!?
        console.log(222);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: タイトルには304、本文には302と書かれていますが、正しくはどちらでしょうか？

Comment: 失礼しました。304が正しいです。修正しました。

Comment: 304は「更新されていないからキャッシュを使うように」というレスポンスですから、一般にエラーではありません。そのため[jQueryでもsuccess扱い](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.4/src/ajax.js#L701)です。「処理自体は正常に動く」とも書かれていますが、なぜ304が問題で、どうハンドリングしたいのでしょうか？

Comment: なるほど！ 304 はエラーではないのですね。
確かに「処理自体は正常に動く」は語弊がありました。

「品目を選択 → ajax → 画面に品目を追加」を繰り返し行い、最後に POST します。
その際、選んだ品目全てがパラメータ化されます。

この時、画面の表示は正しく表示されているのですが POST 時に品目が欠落してしまいます。

例えば「3個の品目を追加し、3個表示されるが POST すると1個欠落とかになってしまう」です。

Comment: 質問内容が分かり難かったので冒頭部分を書き直しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

実行していないので、あくまで推測ですが・・・

304 Not modifiedが返って来た場合、キャッシュからビューが生成されるはずです。
つまり、画面上は304の場合でも品目は追加されていますが、そのHTMLは前回キャッシュされたものになっているかと思われます。要するに以下のコードの部分が一意にならないということです。

```
:child_index => Time.now.to_i
```

試しに品目を何個か追加して、304が出た品目のフィールドのnameが他の品目と重複していないか確認してみてください。もし重複していたらそれが原因です。重複パラメータはPOST時にマージされますので。

とりあえずの対応策は、$.getではなく$.ajaxメソッドを使用して、オプションで

```
cache: false
```

を指定しておけば、304は発生しなくなると思います。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841425/how-to-set-cache-false-in-jquery-get-call

（しかし、ややトリッキーな作りになっているような気がしますので、根本的に修正すべきかも。。。）

Comment: 推測は全て BINGO でした。
そして、 cache: false で 304 が発生しなくなりました。
ありがとうございます! 

トリッキーな作りのご指摘は「やっぱりそうですか。そうですよね…」といった感じですが、根本的にどうしたらいいのかが分からない状態です(T_T)